# NgFor with Comma separated Values

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a user entered string in this format

```
string = "1,5,12,66"
```

I want to simply do a ngFor over the values `1 5 12 66` and my code is

```
<div *ngFor="let number of arrString" ng-if="number!=','">
    <a class="item item-icon-right font-12">
       <b>{{number}}</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

The problem that my code shows

> 1
>
> 5
>
> 1 (should show 12)
>
> 2
>
> 6
>
> 6 (should show 66)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: not ng-if, but *ngIf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`string.Split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method to create an array of strings as follows and loop over them

```
 Mystring = '1,5,12,66';
 arrString = this.Mystring.split(',');
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzyjm2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
stringData = "1,5,12,66"
arrString = this.stringData.split(',');

<div *ngFor="let number of arrString">
    <a class="item item-icon-right font-12">
       <b>{{number}}</b>
    </a>
</div>
```